# Pass QTableView model to another thread and operate with it

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, model

I'm stuck at a learning project.
I've subclassed `QObject`, and set up a signal to work with a `QAbstractItemModel` derived object.
I see like I "received" the object passed in the signal from the GUI thread, and `qDebug`-ing it shows it holds the same address, however, when I try to modify the data in it through `setData` in the separated thread, the program crashes.

What can I do to "modify" this `QTableView` model from another thread?
Or should I create a new model in the thread and pass it back to GUI thread? (is this possible, if yes, how so?)

Comment: Posting some sample code might be helpful.

Comment: You can't use setData from a non-GUI thread. You can (e.g.) emit a signal with a new data from the non-GUI thread and connect it to a slot in your model in the gui thread.

Comment: @Fabio is probably right.

Comment: @Fabio Why not? Where can I find that restriction?

Comment: Recommended reading about Qt threads and issues in general: http://wiki.qt.io/ThreadsEventsQObjects

Comment: @Fabio That was what I was suggested, alongside making a thread inside the custom model and passing a non-qobject class wich has no thread-affinity and contains the model data, just being aware of making it thread-safe.. I'm currently trying to achieve the later, if I can't do it, I'll recurse to your named solution